# Ajax POST from Shopify checkout page

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, post, shopify

I have a checkout.liquid file in shopify were I'm trying to set the metadata to a customers profile.
This is the code I have in the checkout.liquid file:

```
var url = "/admin/customer/"+{{checkout.customer.id}}+"/metafields.json";
console.log("url:"+url);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:url,
    namespace: 'QQQQQQQ',
    key: 'WWWWWWW',
    value: 'Test'
    success: function(msg){
        console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

I get this error in the console:
GET https://checkout.shopify.com/admin/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
I don't understad what's happening?
Do I not have permissions from the checkout.liquid page to access the API or is it something else?

Comment: You can access the API only through an app. Shopify is very strict about it.

Also the url is wrong. It should be :- https://<shopify_store>.myshopify.com/admin/customer/<id>/metafields.json"

Checkout URL is different from the store.